# Firestore create security rule not behaving as expected

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I created a jobs collection with a job document having a job id (XAXhAJh71hHbe1fY7blZ) and added the following security rules:

```
match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if false;
}

match /jobs/{jobId} {  
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) create "Applies to writes to nonexistent documents". 
Namely if the document exists this operation should be rejected.

However the Firestore simulator allows to create over existing document id.
Namely executing create on /jobs/XAXhAJh71hHbe1fY7blZ is being allowed by the emulator even though that the document exists in the database.

[Firestore simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYa4G.png)

Comment: What was your complete create path? Something like "/jobs/O7QCmibazkIBBMgFH1hl/documents/......"

Comment: You can see the screenshot link. The path is /jobs/XAXhAJh71hHbe1fY7blZ and it creates a data object on that object even though that document already exists (against the security rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the definition of create.  Your second sentence here isn't correct:

> According to the docs create "Applies to writes to nonexistent
>   documents". Namely if the document exists this operation should be
>   rejected.

The create rule doesn't reject anything if the document is already present.  If the document is already present and being updated, the create rule doesn't apply at all.  Instead, any update or write rules will apply.  If no matching update or write rules allow access to the document, then the update will be rejected.